# Menu text color move effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My menu looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="black">Home</span>
        <span class="red active">Home</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="black">Longer menu item</span>
        <span class="red">Longer menu item</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#;">
        <span class="black">Two words</span>
        <span class="red">Two words</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="black">About</span>
        <span class="red">About</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="black">Contact</span>
        <span class="red">Contact</span>
    </a>
</nav>
```

The active menu item has red color. When the user clicks on a link, the red color should go right from the active menu item, and in the same time the clicked link should turn red starting from left to right.

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1w4gy0w/)** to show you what I mean. Click on the second link, and after that the third link to see the effect.

If you go from left to right the clicked link turns red beautifully, But the initial red text moves to right, instead of moving only the color.

What should I do to repair this effect?
How can I make this effect to work in left direction too?

Any suggestions are welcome.

***Edit:***
To clear things up: I would like [this effect](http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/DirectionAwareHoverEffect/), but on text. If you move the mouse on the first row from left to right and back, you'll see the effect. I want in on click, not on hover.

There are 2 cases:

1. a menu item is clicked on the right side of the active link -> the color effect should go to right.
2. a menu item is clicked on the left side of the active link -> the color effect should go to left

Comment: Just saying, but I think things with ``position: absolute`` always cover non ``absolute`` elements regardless of ``z-index``.

Comment: If they are directly above each other, choose whichever way you want?

Comment: I haven't thought about this case... It doesn't mater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this: http://jsfiddle.net/t1w4gy0w/3/

Updated for both ways: http://jsfiddle.net/t1w4gy0w/4/

Slight improvement if user presses quickly: http://jsfiddle.net/t1w4gy0w/5/

```js
$('.blackholder').parent().on('click', function(event) {

    if ($(this)[0] === $('.red.active').parent()[0]) {
        return;
    }

    var animFull = function (obj) {
        obj.addClass('top').finish()
        .css('width', '0').animate({ width: '100%'}, {
            duration: 1000,
            queue: false,
            complete: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('top');
            }
        });
    };

    var moveRight = function (atag) {
        animFull(
            $('.red.active').removeClass('active').siblings('.black')
        );

        animFull(
            $(atag).children('.red').addClass('active')
        );
    };

    var animZero = function (obj) {
        obj.addClass('top').finish()
        .animate({ width: '0'}, {
            duration: 1000, queue: false,
            complete: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('top').css('width', '100%'); 
            }
        });
    };

    var moveLeft = function (atag) {
        animZero(
            $('.red.active').removeClass('active')
        );

        $(atag).children('.red').addClass('active');
        animZero(
            $(atag).children('.black')
        );
    };

    if ($('.red.active').parent().position().left < $(this).position().left) {
        moveRight(this);
    } else {
        moveLeft(this);
    }

});
```

```css
.blackholder {
    color: #000;
}
.black.top, .red.top {
    z-index: 3;
}
.black {
    z-index: 1;
    color: #000;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.red {
    color: red;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.red.active {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="blackholder">Home</span>
        <span class="black">Home</span>
        <span class="red active">Home</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="blackholder">Longer menu item</span>
        <span class="black">Longer menu item</span>
        <span class="red">Longer menu item</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="blackholder">Two words</span>
        <span class="black">Two words</span>
        <span class="red">Two words</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="blackholder">About</span>
        <span class="black">About</span>
        <span class="red">About</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="blackholder">Contact</span>
        <span class="black">Contact</span>
        <span class="red">Contact</span>
    </a>
</nav>
```

If you need any changes, like me adding comments to code, feel free to comment.

Comment: YES! This is the effect for case 1! But can you make it work in case 2? _(See edited question)_

Comment: @Barnee updated for slight improvement if user presses too quickly

Comment: The green tick next to your answer shows my gratitude! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for, from red to black and from black to red http://jsfiddle.net/t1w4gy0w/2/

```
$('.black').on('click', function (event) {
    $('.red').animate({
        width: 0
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
    }).removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find('.red').addClass('active').animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
    });
});
```

And change CSS

```
.red {
    top: 0;
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    color: red;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.red.active {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$('.black').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.red').css({'width': 0}).removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('.red').addClass('active').animate({ width: '100%'}, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
    });
});
```

If you want your color sliding left try to fix `.red` left, it's looks like **width = 0** goes to the right corner